# Getting error "An account required by the instruction is missing" while creating associated token address

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-test, token-2022, anchor-spl

I am trying to create associated token address on solana program with below configuration

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(params: TokenParams)]
pub struct MintToken<'info> {    
    /// CHECK: This is the token that we want to mint
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"mint"],
        bump,
        mint::authority = authority,
    )]
    pub mint_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = authority,
        associated_token::mint = mint_account,
        associated_token::authority = authority,
        associated_token::token_program = token_program,
    )]
    pub token_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,

    /// CHECK: the authority of the mint account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,

    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
}
```

and test config as

```
   let user1ATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      mintAccount,
      payer.publicKey,
      undefined,
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    );

const mint = async (
    tokenParams,
    pdaMaintainers,
    mintAccount,
    pdaConfig,
    pdaWhitelist,
    user1ATA
  ) => {
 
    let mintToken = await program.methods
      .mintToken(tokenParams)
      .accounts({
        maintainers: pdaMaintainers,
        config: pdaConfig,
        whitelist: pdaWhitelist,
        mintAccount,
        tokenAccount: user1ATA,
        authority: admin.publicKey,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
      .signers([admin])
      .rpc();


    await confirmTransaction(mintToken);
  };
```

But getting the error "An account required by the instruction is missing", but all accounts are available[image]

Comment: Have you tried switching `associated_token::mint` to `token::mint` and `associated_token::authority` to `token::authority`?

Comment: After changing to token::authority and token::mint I am getting error 
{Error: Signature verification failed.
Missing signature for public key [`2NoueZzqVcivrSMcThMqzQdnoQ9SMKHadrdNY9xgR8JL`].}
means it is asking for user1ATA signature, but I don't want to pass user1ATA signature, as the requirement is only one signer can be there